# Array split not giving expected output

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Sir i am trying to split array[i] and storing that into another array but it is not working.
Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prog1 {

  public static void main (String [] args){
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int a = input.nextInt();
      String arr1[] = new String [a];
      for (int i=0;i<a;i++) {
          arr1[i] = input.nextLine();
      }
      for (int i=0;i<a;i++) {
          String temp[] = arr1[i].split("\\+");
          System.out.println(temp.length);
          System.out.println(temp[0]);
      }
  }
}
```

**Sample input :**

```
 1
 arka + xyz
```

**Expected Output :**

```
2
arka
```

**But the output which i am getting**

```
1
<blank>
```

I am new in java . would you please help me to solve this problem as well as tell me why i am facing this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you hit enter after entering a number it is read as the next line.

One way to solve this is to add `input.next()`; right after `int a = input.nextInt();` which will read the return character.  I think then the application will behave as you expect.

Alternatively you could read the number like this.

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 3):

You only read an `int` with `nextInt()` and you didn't consume the end of the first line before reading additional lines in your `for` loop, so the first iteration of the `for` loop reads the end of the first line, not the second line.

Chomp the end of the first line before starting your `for` loop:

```
String chomp = input.nextLine();
for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
    // Then read the following lines here.
```